# recursive grep using python

Tags: python, grep, subprocess, popen

I am new to python and trying to learn. I am trying to implement a simple recursive grep using python for processing and here is what I came to so far.

```
p = subprocess.Popen('find . -name [ch]', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    q = subprocess.Popen('grep searchstring %s', line, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print q.stdout.readlines()
```

Can some one pls tell me how to fix this to do what it is supposed to?

Comment: what does it does that you're not expecting?  are you getting an error?  is the bad indentation on line to in front of `for` your problem or a typo?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the `os.walk` function for going through your files. Use string methods or regex for filtering out the results. Check http://docs.python.org/library/os.html for informations about how to use os.walk.

```
import os
import re

def findfiles(path, regex):
    regObj = re.compile(regex)
    res = []
    for root, dirs, fnames in os.walk(path):
        for fname in fnames:
            if regObj.match(fname):
                res.append(os.path.join(root, fname))
    return res

print findfiles('.', r'my?(reg|ex)')
```

Now for the grep part, you can loop over the file with the `open` function

```
def grep(filepath, regex):
    regObj = re.compile(regex)
    res = []
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for line in f:
            if regObj.match(line):
                res.append(line)
    return res
```

If you want to get the line numbers, you may want to look into the `enumerate` function.

**edited to add the grep function**

Comment: This is really more of a "find", not "recursive grep".

Comment: this is not recursive grep at all, it's just looking at filenames

Comment: @Stephan At the time I just wanted to give some hints on regex and directory traversal. But you are right that grep was a bad function name. I improved my answer a bit.

Comment: This is find not grep. `regObj.match` does a match with the filename.

Answer (score 4):

You can use python-textops3 :

Example, to grep all 'import' in all .py files from current directory :

```
from textops import *

print('\n'.join(('.' | find('*.py') | cat() | grep('import'))))
```

It is pure python, no need to fork a process.

Answer (score 0):

```
p = subprocess.Popen('find . -name [ch]', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    q = subprocess.Popen('grep searchstring %s', line, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print q.stdout.readlines()
```

1. The indentation on line 2 will Exception, the `for` needs to be aligned with the `p` above
2. `'grep searchstring %s', line` will not do the string replacement, you need to replace the `,` with `%`

With those changes and real search values, it works on my OS X box. Final script:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('find . -name *.py', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    print line
    q = subprocess.Popen('grep import %s' % line, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print q.stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: This can still be very dangerous if you had a file named `'; rm /porn -rf; wget -r http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch\&q=ponies --directory-prefix=/ponies; .py'` in the directory.  `Popen(['grep', 'import', line] ...)` is always preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an example can help you, the command `find . -print | grep "python"` is equivalent to this:

```
import subprocess

pc1 = subprocess.Popen('find . -print', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
pc2 = subprocess.Popen('grep "python"', stdin=pc1.stdout, shell=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print pc2.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: You could even shorten this up to: `Popen('find . -print | grep "python"', stdout=PIP, shell=True).communicate()[0]`