# Search directory for string

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to search a directory for a given string pattern in Python. I then want to assemble the matches into an array.

At first, I was trying to use grep:

```
regex = " dojo.require(..*) "
bashCommand = "grep"+" --only-matching -r -h"+regex+baseDir
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
dirStr = process.communicate()[0]
```

But I realized I needed to support strings on multiple lines, such as

```
dojo.require(
"abc"(;
```

so grep is not an option.

What other ways can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012921/recursive-grep-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than calling grep, you could implement this functionality in pure Python using a combination of [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) and [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). Use the [re.DOTALL](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag to allow multi-line matches. For example:

```
import re, os

def grep(regex, base_dir):
    compiled_regex = re.compile(regex, re.DOTALL)
    matches = list()
    for filename in os.listdir(base_dir):
        full_filename = os.path.join(base_dir, filename)
        if not os.path.isfile(full_filename):
            continue
        with open(os.path.join(base_dir, filename)) as fh:
            content = fh.read()
            if compiled_regex.search(content):
                matches.append(full_filename)
    return matches

print grep(" dojo.require(..*) ", ".")
```

Comment: I really like this approach. One thing - how can I grab the actual matches themselves, not the filenames, and put them in the List? I see that the search( ) returns a MatchObject...can I just expand( ) this to grab the actual match itself?

Comment: Use MatchObject.group(0) to grab the entire matched string, or MatchObject.group(1) for just the first match group (i.e. everything in the first parentheses in your regex). However, I think your regex is not escaped properly and will not do what you expect it to. Try changing it to "dojo\.require\\((.*?)\\)", then you should be able to access everything in the parentheses with MatchObject.group(1).

Answer (score 0):

you could use `prcegrep`, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/165634/grep-multiline-pattern).
To achieve that, you would need to adjust the regular expression to be multiline.

You can also build something using:

- `os.walk` to access all files recursively.
- `re.search` to search for the correct expression.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012921/recursive-grep-using-python) has an example.