# Is there an way to get a specific line in string

Tags: python

im trying to make it go to a folder go in to one of the folders in there and if there is not anymore folders then it goes back to start to go to the other folder

```
for folder in os.listdir():
if os.path.isdir(folder):
    print(folder)
else:
    pass
```

Comment: For any sort of directory search like this (a tree structure), you want to make a recursive function. Give the function a starting folder name, and the function prints all the files inside that folder. For each folder inside that folder, the function simply calls itself and it goes on like that until all the folders and sub-folders have been covered. It sounds like that’s what you’re aiming for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recursive grep using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012921/recursive-grep-using-python)

Comment: but i just need a way to print line 1 and line 2 separated

Comment: What do you mean "separated"? The `print` function should print everything you pass to it on its own line.